# has_one from model attributes instead of foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-one

I would like to have a `has_one` relation based on my Product's attributes rather than its id.

```rb
class Pricing
  belongs_to :type
  belongs_to :brand
  validates :type_id, uniqueness: { scope: :brand_id }
end


class Product
  belongs_to :type
  belongs_to :brand

  has_one :pricing # I need to indicate that the matching pricing is the one that has the same brand and type than my product.
end
```

How could we build the `has_one` relations in this scenario?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit about what you are going to accomplish? A scetch of the data model including some attributes might be handy

Comment: A Pricing contains the `price` for said `brand` and `type`. A Product has a `brand` and a `type` - therefore his price the same than the matching `Pricing`

Comment: But why do you have Brand and Type in both entities? For me this does not sound like proper normalization

Comment: It kind of sounds like you're fishing for [Composite Primary Keys](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_composite_primary_keys.html) which is very new rails feature. But it also just looks like your database design is bad and I am also confused at the the why here.

Comment: @zaphodbln_ I'm not sure what to tell you here. We have a webshop selling secondhand clothes. A `Product` (clothe in real life) has a `Brand` (Nike), a `Type` (T-shirt) and a `price` attribute. `Brands` and `Types` are store in their own model. We need to calculate the `price` for each `Product` and as we are a secondhand shop we decided to price our product on a %age of the price of a new item. Therefore we have introduce a new model called `Pricing`  referencing a `Brand` (Nike) and a `Type` (T-shirts) with an attribute `price` that represent the median price of a new Nike T-Shirt.

Comment: If we could have a `has_one` relation in the `Product` pointing at a `Pricing` we could then have a price based on `product.pricing.price * 0.75`. Does this make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - to sum it from the comments I understand your logical data model as following:

**Product** <<- The Product in the shop

- Type
- Brand
- Price   <<- to be charged to the customer

**Pricing**  <<- Reference for a comparable new product

- Type
- Brand
- Reference Price

In this case you can try to use the composite key feature as mentioned by max. So you might try:

```
class Product
  belongs_to :type
  belongs_to :brand

  has_one :pricing, query_constraints: [:type_id, :brand_id]
end
```

Please be aware that you need Rails 7.1 for this. As this is a new feature expect to have a change in the syntax in one of the next releases :)

However, you may want to rethink your design. From my understanding you could combine both entities:

**Product**

- Type
- Brand
- Price   <<- to be charged to the customer
- Reference Price    <<- of the new product

Or you factor out Brand and Type into a single entity and use the through-option (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many --> similar for has_one)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `has_one` API for such a scenario doesn't really make sense, the contortions that would be required in the Rails code to support this unusual requirement would massively overcomplicate the code for the 99.9% case.

It seems unlikely that you want anything other than the getter, so just write that yourself:

```rb
def pricing = Pricing.find_sole_by type: type, brand: brand
```